# QGIS - map with gradient background according to numbers

Tags: qgis

I am looking for a way to create a map in QGIS :-D
I want it to have a lighter version of a color for a number that is less.
Similar to this one.

I know that it is in layer -> properties -> symbol
but I cannot figure out the exact way from there :-D

Any chance that any of you might be able to help?

[image]

I checked a number of values and boxes, but wasn't able to get it working.
I am trying to recreate this exact map and have the data.